# How can i Shuffle two js arrays without mismatching them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a shuffle feature similar to youtube music that shuffles the list order when you click the button (not just randomly choosing a song and ignoring the list order). but I haven't been able to shuffle them without mismatching the pairs.

this is for an updated feature of VisuJams. I've tried a couple of answers on other peoples posted questions, but the page just ends up ignoring the shuffle feature.

```
this.fileNames = [
//some song files
    ];

this.trackTitles = [
//matching song titles
    ];
window.onload = shuffleorder()

function shuffleorder(){
//part i cannot figure out :(
}
```

what I want is for the script to be able to shuffle both lists, without mismatching the pairs and hopefully have the page actually acknowledge the action

Comment: _without mismatching the pairs_ ... which pairs? please provide a reproducible scenario. There are tons of questions about shuffling.

Comment: why are the track titles and file names separate? Store them as an array of objects with each object containing the title and filename.

Comment: So, you have 2 arrays with same length and the only thing connecting each data is the index? Create an array of objects with `fileName` and `trackTitle` properties and store them in a single array

Comment: Also notice you are directly invoking the function. `window.onload = shuffleorder()` should be `window.onload = shuffleorder`

Comment: @briosheje the fileNames and trackTitles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented it would be way better to store the fileNames and the tracks as a combined object inside a single array.

Anyway, if you want to use two arrays, you have to make sure that you randomize the same elements in both arrays. So if you switch element 3 with element 1 of fileNames, do the same with trackTitles.

Here's a sample:

```js
this.fileNames = ["fileA", "fileB", "fileC"];
this.trackTitles = ["titleA", "titleB", "titleC"];

function shuffle() {
  var tempA;
  var tempB;
  for (var a = 0; a < fileNames.length; a++) {
    tempA = fileNames[a];
    tempB = Math.floor(Math.random() * fileNames.length);
    fileNames[a] = fileNames[tempB];
    fileNames[tempB] = tempA;

    tempA = trackTitles[a];
    trackTitles[a] = trackTitles[tempB];
    trackTitles[tempB] = tempA;
  }
}

shuffle();
console.log(fileNames);
console.log(trackTitles);
```

Answer (score 1):

Randomize it using this method:

```js
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3];
var currentIndex = array1.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
while (0 !== currentIndex) {
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
  currentIndex -= 1;
  temporaryValue = array1[currentIndex];
  array1[currentIndex] = array1[randomIndex];
  array1[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  temporaryValue = array2[currentIndex];
  array2[currentIndex] = array2[randomIndex];
  array2[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```